# Accept remote input for carbon

Tags: monitoring, graphite

I'm running a freshly installed graphite monitoring server and I can send in data to carbon fine on the local machine, but when trying to send in data from a remote machine via the example.py script (where I changed the IP address in the top), I only get a connection refused. Same if I try via telnet.

I have read up and down the docs but seem to not find what I'm doing wrong.

Any hints on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Same if I try via telnet.

Doesn't seem to be a 'graphite problem' but rather a networking one.

1. Make sure that carbon is listening on the port. If your local script can send data, it is.
2. Next, you need to figure out why a remote instance cannot connect to the listening port(2003?). Most probably, a firewall is involved. Add incoming exception for port 2003 in your firewall, or open up the 'security groups' if you're on Amazon web services.